# How can I allow to create a new object both for registered and unregistered users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Calendar app both registered and unregistered users can create a meeting. In my **meetings_controller** :

```
def new
    @meeting = Meeting.new
    @meeting = current_user.meetings.new(meeting_params) if current_user 
    
  end
def create
     
    respond_to do |format|
      if @meeting.save
        format.html { redirect_to @meeting, notice: 'Meeting was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @meeting }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
def meeting_params
      params.require(:meeting).permit(:name, :start_time)
    end
```

So, if a current_user exists it creates current_user.meetings.new(meeting_params) and if not, it should create just a Meeting.new without any user. However, it doesn't work and I get an error:

> undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @meeting.save
>     format.html { redirect_to @meeting, notice: 'Meeting was successfully created.' }
>     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @meeting }
>   else
> ```

It works well if there is a current_user, but why the meeting without a user defines as 'nill' if I mentioned that it shout be just a Meeting_new? How can I make it work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller code as like :

```
def new
  @meeting = Meeting.new 
end
def create
   @meeting = Meeting.new(meeting_params)  #edit
  @meeting.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @meeting.save
      format.html { redirect_to @meeting, notice: 'Meeting was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @meeting }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
def meeting_params
  params.require(:meeting).permit(:name, :start_time, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: @Guarav Thank you, but it didn't help, the same error. (

Comment: @Guarav Yes, it helped! Thank you!